# Progress dialog not stopped in async task

Tags: android, progressdialog

i want to close progress dialog onPostexecute method but it didn't close. i don't know why. i create lots of asyntask that is worked properly but i don't know why this is not work.i try to print some log it will display properly in onPostexecute and there is not any exception occured.my data came properly and it stored in sqlite database.i not used execute.get() method. below some code that i tried.

```
public class AsynctaskProof extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe>> 
{

    proofInterface call;
    Context context;
    String resString, stcode, resStr,proofIdFetch,proofNameFetch,proofIdTag,proofNameTag,methodName,envelope;
    BaseActivity ba;
    Object objectType;
    JSONObject object,jsonObject;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    public ProofDetailsGeSe proofgese;
    public static ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe> proofArray;

    public AsynctaskProof(Context c, proofInterface callback, String tag1, String tag2) {
        context = c;
        proofIdTag =tag1;
        proofNameTag =tag2;
        call = callback;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        ba = new BaseActivity();
        db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        proofgese = new ProofDetailsGeSe();
        proofArray = new ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe>();
        ba.showProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe> proofDetailsGeSes) {
        super.onPostExecute(proofDetailsGeSes);
        Log.d("come2 in post1","dfvds");

        ba.closeProgressDialog();
        call.run(proofDetailsGeSes);
        Log.d("comes in post2","dfvds");
    }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe> doInBackground(String... params) {

        methodName = params[0];
        resStr = sRequestClass.getProof();

        envelope = ba.soapRequestdata(resStr, methodName);
        resString = ba.sendSoapData(context,envelope);

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(resString.substring(resString.indexOf("{"), resString.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
            Log.d("jsonObject  group2", "" + jsonObject);
            object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("MRRESP");
            String  stcode1 = object.getString("STCODE");

            ResponseString.setStcode(stcode1);
            if (stcode1.equals("0")) {
                db.deleteData(DatabaseHelper.sqtable_ProofDetails);

                proofgese = new ProofDetailsGeSe();

                proofgese.setProofId(0);
                proofgese.setProofName("Select");

                proofArray.add(proofgese);

                JSONArray stmsg = object.getJSONArray("STMSG");

                for (int i = 0; i < stmsg.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject detail = stmsg.getJSONObject(i);

                    proofIdFetch = detail.getString(proofIdTag);
                    proofNameFetch = detail.getString(proofNameTag);

                    proofgese = new ProofDetailsGeSe();

                    proofgese.setProofId(Integer.parseInt(proofIdFetch));
                    proofgese.setProofName(proofNameFetch);

                    db.saveProof(DatabaseHelper.sqtable_ProofDetails,Integer.parseInt(proofIdFetch),proofNameFetch);

                    proofArray.add(proofgese);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                BaseActivity.sMsg = object.getString("STMSG");
                Log.d("error " ,""+ BaseActivity.sMsg);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return proofArray;
    }
}
```

below is the function for create dialog and display it

```
    public void showProgressDialog(Context c) {
            pleaseWaitDialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
pleaseWaitDialog.setMessage(c.getResources().getString(R.string.waitMsg));
        pleaseWaitDialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        pleaseWaitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pleaseWaitDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.progress);
        pleaseWaitDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pleaseWaitDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pleaseWaitDialog.show();
    }
```

below is function that i used for close dialog

```
public static void closeProgressDialog() {
    if ((pleaseWaitDialog != null) && pleaseWaitDialog.isShowing()) {
        pleaseWaitDialog.dismiss();
        pleaseWaitDialog = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: i can't understand this - "at first call onPostExecute after doInBackground"

Comment: remove the isShowing() check

Comment: call `onPostExecute` method  after `doInBackground`  and comment `pleaseWaitDialog = null;`

Comment: if i am remove it sometime i get exception of leakage so i added it

Comment: ohkk..i will try..

Comment: thanks intellij Amiya and cool java guy for your quick replay...

Comment: @Varshilshah give me feedback

Comment: you can comment `pleaseWaitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);`

Comment: @ IntelliJ Amiya ..i get some network issue in application when i tried   i will tell you

Comment: @Varshilshah as your wish

Comment: i tried as you say..but still problem is  occurred.. progress dialog still not closed

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code like this

```
public class AsynctaskProof extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe>> 
{

proofInterface call;
Context context;
String resString, stcode, resStr,proofIdFetch,proofNameFetch,proofIdTag,proofNameTag,methodName,envelope;
BaseActivity ba;
Object objectType;
JSONObject object,jsonObject;
DatabaseHelper db;
public ProofDetailsGeSe proofgese;
public static ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe> proofArray;

public AsynctaskProof(Context c, proofInterface callback, String tag1, String tag2) {
    context = c;
    proofIdTag =tag1;
    proofNameTag =tag2;
    call = callback;
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    ba = new BaseActivity();
    db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    proofgese = new ProofDetailsGeSe();
    proofArray = new ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe>();

    // Showing progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe> doInBackground(String... params) {

    methodName = params[0];
    resStr = sRequestClass.getProof();

    envelope = ba.soapRequestdata(resStr, methodName);
    resString = ba.sendSoapData(context,envelope);

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(resString.substring(resString.indexOf("{"), resString.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
        Log.d("jsonObject  group2", "" + jsonObject);
        object = jsonObject.getJSONObject("MRRESP");
        String  stcode1 = object.getString("STCODE");

        ResponseString.setStcode(stcode1);
        if (stcode1.equals("0")) {
            db.deleteData(DatabaseHelper.sqtable_ProofDetails);

            proofgese = new ProofDetailsGeSe();

            proofgese.setProofId(0);
            proofgese.setProofName("Select");

            proofArray.add(proofgese);

            JSONArray stmsg = object.getJSONArray("STMSG");

            for (int i = 0; i < stmsg.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject detail = stmsg.getJSONObject(i);

                proofIdFetch = detail.getString(proofIdTag);
                proofNameFetch = detail.getString(proofNameTag);

                proofgese = new ProofDetailsGeSe();

                proofgese.setProofId(Integer.parseInt(proofIdFetch));
                proofgese.setProofName(proofNameFetch);

                db.saveProof(DatabaseHelper.sqtable_ProofDetails,Integer.parseInt(proofIdFetch),proofNameFetch);

                proofArray.add(proofgese);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            BaseActivity.sMsg = object.getString("STMSG");
            Log.d("error " ,""+ BaseActivity.sMsg);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return proofArray;
   }

  @Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<ProofDetailsGeSe> proofDetailsGeSes) {
    super.onPostExecute(proofDetailsGeSes);
    Log.d("come2 in post1","dfvds");

    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    call.run(proofDetailsGeSes);
    Log.d("comes in post2","dfvds");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check it with the edited answer. I have changed the progress dialog.

Comment: hey Saira thank you..so much..my problem solved..but i can't understand what is the problem..because i have other asynctask class that all run proper only this is not run proper why??